# Incorrect CC link on help page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, licensing, creative-commons

The Creative Commons Attribution-Share Alike link on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) still links to the 3.0 license.

It should instead be [4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) - see [the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333089/284827).

Comment: @animuson - it still says 3.0 at the bottom of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) pages - I guess that, too, should be updated.